# Calling a method through an ill-typed pointer? Is it legal?

Tags: c++, casting, type-conversion, language-lawyer

The Standard tells us<sup>1</sup> in an example<sup>2</sup> than the following is legal:

```
struct T1 { int a, b; };
struct T2 { int c; double d; };
union U { T1 t1; T2 t2; };
int f() {
  U u = { { 1, 2 } };   // active member is t1
  return u.t2.c;        // OK, as if u.t1.a were nominated
}
```

Now, adding an indirection level (member function) and removing another (union), I wonder:

**Is the following well-defined?**

```
struct T1      { int a; int value() { return a; }};
struct T2 : T1 { int b; };
int f() {
  T1 t1 = { 1 };
  return reinterpret_cast<T2*>(&t1)->value();
}
```

I know the cast is not undefined behavior<sup>3</sup> by itself; but is the `->` operator on its result infringing `[basic.lval]/11`<sup>4</sup>? or are we saved by `[expr.ref]/4`<sup>5</sup>?

I want to think it is legal since `t1.a` and `reinterpret_cast<T2*>(&t1)->a` have *the same address*<sup>6</sup> (hence the same offset in their representation). But is it?

---

<sup>1)</sup> [`[class.mem]/22`](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.mem#22) and [`[class.mem]/23`](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.mem#23) define what *layout-compatible classes* are; [`[class.mem]/25`](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.mem#25) gives us:

> In a *standard-layout union* with an active member of struct type `T1`, it is permitted to read a non-static data member m of another union member of struct type `T2` provided `m` is part of the *common initial sequence* of `T1` and `T2`; the behavior is as if the corresponding member of `T1` were nominated.

<sup>2)</sup> In [`[class.mem]/25`](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.mem#25.example-1).

<sup>3)</sup> [`[expr.reinterpret.cast]/7`](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.reinterpret.cast#7):

> An object pointer can be explicitly converted to an object pointer of a different type. When a prvalue v of object pointer type is converted to the object pointer type “pointer to `cv T`”, the result is `static_­cast<cv T*>(static_­cast<cv void*>(v))`.

and [`[expr.static.cast]/13`](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.static.cast#13)

> A prvalue of type “pointer to *cv1* `void`” can be converted to a prvalue of type “pointer to *cv2* `T`”, where `T` is an object type and *cv2* is the same cv-qualification as, or greater cv-qualification than, *cv1*. If the original pointer value represents the address `A` of a byte in memory and `A` does not satisfy the alignment requirement of `T`, then the resulting pointer value is unspecified. Otherwise, if the original pointer value points to an object `a`, and there is an object `b` of type `T` (ignoring cv-qualification) that is pointer-interconvertible with `a`, the result is a pointer to `b`. Otherwise, the pointer value is unchanged by the conversion.

<sup>4)</sup> [`[basic.lval]/11`](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lval#11)

> If a program attempts to access the stored value of an object through a glvalue of other than one of the following types the behavior is undefined:
>
> - [ rules not applicable ]
> - (11.6) an aggregate or union type that includes one of the aforementioned types among its elements or non-static data members (including, recursively, an element or non-static data member of a subaggregate or contained union),
> - [ rules not applicable ]

<sup>5)</sup> [`[expr.ref]/4`](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.ref#4.sentence-4) on postfix expression involving the notation `E1.E2` or `E1->E2`.

<sup>6)</sup> [`[class.mem]/26`](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.mem#26)

> If a *standard-layout class* object has any non-static data members, its address is the same as the address of its first non-static data member if that member is not a bit-field. Its address is also the same as the address of each of its base class subobjects.

Comment: I've put a lot of effort in this question. If you downvote it, please tell me why so I can improve it.

Comment: I'm going to tentatively say that this question is a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule

Answer (score 2):

No, that's UB as far as I can tell.

I don't see how [expr.ref]p4 can save you. You are accessing an object of type `T1` through a pointer of a different type (which is also not the dynamic type of the object).

Also, [class.mem]p26 is not relevant as you are already violating [basic.lval]p11.

Comment: Unrelated? `T2` inherit from `T1`.

Comment: Yes, but you got a `T1` not a `T2`. T2 is related to T1, but not the other way around I guess. I'll rephrase.